# generating (and installing) doxygen documentation with autotools

Tags: doxygen, autotools, libtool

i'm writing a library (using libtools), where all the API documentation is done using doxygen.

i wonder whether there is an easy way to integrate the installation of the generated doxygen documentation into autotools.

i figure that building the documentation should be easy enough.
but once i ran doxygen, what is the proper way to get the generated (e.g.) .html files into $(htmldir)?

the problem seems to be that i don't know (nor do i want to know) which files doxygen is going to create for me, so i cannot really enumerate them all into html_DATA

i figure something like 'html_DATA=html/*.*' is a **bad** idea

Answer (score 5):

It might be more compact to use some contributed MACROs.  Here I have figure out a simple method based on the examples from the AUTOTOOLS book by John Calcote pg 246.

Add the following to configure.ac just above the

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
```

line

```
AC_CHECK_PROGS([DOXYGEN], [doxygen])
if test -z "$DOXYGEN"; then
   AC_MSG_WARN([Doxygen not found - continue without Doxygen support])
fi
AC_CHECK_PROGS([DOT], [dot])
if test -z "$DOT"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([Doxygen needs dot, please install dot first])
fi
AC_CHECK_PROGS([PDFLATEX], [pdflatex])
if test -z "$PDFLATEX"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([Doxygen needs pdflatex program, it is part of TeX http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html])
fi
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_DOXYGEN], [test -n "$DOXYGEN"])
AM_COND_IF([HAVE_DOXYGEN], [AC_CONFIG_FILES([docs/Doxyfile])])
AM_COND_IF([HAVE_DOXYGEN], [AC_CONFIG_FILES([docs/Makefile])])
```

In the PROJECTDIR/docs directory

add two files: Doxyfile.in and Makefile.am

Use Substitution variable for example:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = @PACKAGE_NAME@
PROJECT_NUMBER         = @PACKAGE_VERSION@
INPUT                  = @top_srcdir@
```

Then make proper modification to other doxygen configuration fields.

```
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
```

This way you will generate pdf file.

The Makefile.am should be simple:

```
if HAVE_DOXYGEN
directory = $(top_srcdir)/docs/man/man3

man_MANS = $(directory)

$(directory): doxyfile.stamp

doxyfile.stamp: Doxyfile
    $(DOXYGEN) $^
    cd latex && $(MAKE)
    echo Timestamp > $@

CLEANFILES = doxyfile.stamp

all-local: doxyfile.stamp
clean-local:
    -rm -rf $(top_srcdir)/docs/man

endif
```

(Make sure you respect Makefile indentation while copying this.)

This seemed to have worked for me. The resulting documentation is generated in the docs folder. Please let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: `$(top_builddir)/docs/man` instead of `$(top_srcdir)/docs/man`

Answer (score 1):

I use the macro of Oren Ben-Kiki, see [GitHub](https://github.com/bbc/vc2hqdecode/blob/master/doxygen.am), [GNU autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_doxygen.html)  or Google it. The script creates the doxygen documentation in PDF/HTML/man (configurable) format.

Add your generated help files to the  *dist_doc_DATA* list in Makefile.am, to have them installed.

Comment: Good answer, but the link is outdated. Please update it.